# How to make Glide keep connection alive?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using the Android Glide library to load images remotely.

The image URL protocol is `https` so there is a performance implication due to TSL every time a new connection is established.

I'm using the okhttp integration:

```
def glide_version = "4.10.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$glide_version"
```

Is it possible to make Glide keep the connection alive for better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up an HTTP client with a custom ConnectionPool. Take a look at the connection pool's constructor:

```
public ConnectionPool(int maxIdleConnections, long keepAliveDuration, TimeUnit timeUnit)
```

So you can try something like:

```
@GlideModule
class YourGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry
                .replace(
                        GlideUrl::class.java,
                        InputStream::class.java,
                        OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(
                                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                        .connectionPool(ConnectionPool(5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                                        .build()))
    }
}
```

Those are default values, but you can find the ones that suit you.

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that _by default_ Glide has a 5min keep alive timeout? In other words, if we don't use a custom connection pool, Glide is already keeping the connection alive for 5 mins?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I saw in 4.9.0 source code.